# Terminal - No such file or directory exists

Tags: terminal

So complete newbie question, but I've googled it and tried all their suggestions and I can't get it to work still :(

Trying to learn about the terminal... so I've created two files on my Desktop - filea.txt, fileb.txt - when I try to run the cd command I get the error, "No such file or directory exists".

I'm in the Desktop so that isn't the problem.

Is there anyone who could please suggest anything I can try?

I appreciate the help, and am completely grateful to anyone who answers - I understand time is valuable.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to change to? Are you trying to go up a directory level?

Comment: CD is change directory command and you are trying to execute it on file that's why you are getting that error.

Comment: which command u are running?

Comment: to view that file type `cat filea.txt` or open it in vi editor by typing `vi filea.txt`.

Comment: is there a reason why the cat filea.txt command would work? I'm still getting the same error - No such file or directory. I've run the ls command and can see the files there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to change directory to desktop and it's giving you that error, try typing `cd ..` which goes back one directory, and repeat to go back as far as you can and then try changing directory to desktop again.

Comment: Sorry... should have checked what i wrote... I'm trying to run the cat filea.txt command.

Comment: It's just a simple exercise trying to get familiar with terminal, which I can't seem to get working

Comment: @NicolaWells Are you using windows or ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using the terminal app on my mac... would it help if I used something else?

Comment: thanks for your help! kept playing and all i needed to do was leave the .txt off the end of the file. Command worked fine then :) Thanks for taking the time to answer, and help out. It's appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

On an ubuntu to change to `Desktop`, you should type `cd ~/Desktop`, now you are in the `Desktop` directory, now typing `ls` would should list your files and directories on your desktop. Now you can open your file on a text editing application such as gedit by typing `gedit filea.txt`, which would open the file `filea.txt` in the text editor.

Comment: thanks... that's really helpful. I'm trying to run the command cat filea.txt. I can see that the file is listed on the Desktop, but it won't recognise that the file is there

Comment: @NicolaWells so the `ls` command shows the files on ur desktop?, but "what" wont recognise that the file is there?

Comment: @NicolaWells Between, if u created the empty `filea.txt` and u did not add any contents to the file, it means the file is empty and running `cat filea.txt` command wont do anything and it will appear as though `cat filea.txt` is not working. So if u want to test the `cat` command, u should first add contents to the file by opening it in a text editor, by issuing a command such as `gedit filea.txt`.

Comment: Thanks... managed to work it out by going through the list again... seems I just needed to leave the .txt off the end of the file name and that pulled up the contents. Thanks for taking the time to answer and run this through with me. I know questions like this can be frustrating!